# Javascript button plays random sound

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm new to this and need some (maybe a lot of) help. I want a be able to press a single button and have a random sound play from it. I think what I'm doing is right so far but I don't really know how to make it work.

Here's my Javascript

```
function mySounds()
  {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  var sound = ["sound1", "sound2", "sound3", "sound4", "sound5", "sound6",  "sound7", "sound8", "sound9", "sound10"];
  }

sound1 = 1;
sound2 = 2;
sound3 = 3;
sound4 = 4;
sound5 = 5;
sound6 = 6;
sound7 = 7;
sound8 = 8;
sound9 = 9;
sound10 = 10;

if (x === sound1){
  function sound1play(){
    var sound1 = new Audio();
    sound1.src = "Pokemon.mp3";
    sound1.play();
  }
}
if (x === sound2){
  function sound2play() {
    var sound2 = new Audio();
    sound2.src = "Wonderwall.mp3";
    sound2.play();
    }
  }
if (x === sound3){
  function sound3play() {
    var sound3 = new Audio();
    sound3.src = "Tacobell.mp3";
    sound3.play();
    }
  }
if (x === sound4){
  function sound4play() {
    var sound4 = new Audio();
    sound4.src = "Starwars.mp3";
    sound4.play();
    }
  }
if (x === sound5){
  function sound5play() {
    var sound5 = new Audio();
    sound5.src = "Mcdonalds.mp3";
    sound5.play();
    }
  }
if (x === sound6){
  function sound6play() {
    var sound6 = new Audio();
    sound6.src = "KFC.mp3";
    sound6.play();
    }
  }
if (x === sound7){
  function sound7play() {
    var sound7 = new Audio();
    sound7.src = "Salvia.mp3";
    sound7.play();
    }
  }
if (x === sound8){
  function sound8play() {
    var sound8 = new Audio();
    sound8.src = "Allstar.mp3";
    sound8.play();
    }
  }
if (x === sound9){
  function sound9play() {
    var sound9 = new Audio();
    sound9.src = "Funtime.mp3";
    sound9.play();
    }
  }
if (x === sound10){
  function sound10play() {
    var sound10 = new Audio();
    sound10.src = "Clothes.mp3";
    sound10.play();
    }
  }
document.getElementById('soundbutton').addEventListener('click', soundplay);
```

Here's my HTML

```
 <a href="#" id="soundbutton">Press</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="popup.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is something not working? You only described the goal, not the specific problem you faced.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function mySounds() {
  var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    var sound = new Audio();
  switch (x) {
    case 1:
         sound.src = "Pokemon.mp3";
         break;
    case 2:
         sound.src = "Wonderwall.mp3";
         break;
    case 3:
         sound.src = "Tacobell.mp3";
         break;
    case 4:
         sound.src = "Starwars.mp3";
         break;
    case 5:
         sound.src = "Mcdonalds.mp3";
         break;
    case 6:
         sound.src = "KFC.mp3";
         break;
    case 7:
         sound.src = "Salvia.mp3";
         break;
    case 8:
         sound.src = "Allstar.mp3";
         break;
    case 9:
         sound.src = "Funtime.mp3";
         break;
    case 10:
         sound.src = "Clothes.mp3";
         break;
  }
    sound.play();
}

document.getElementById('soundbutton').addEventListener('click', mySounds);
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the way I would recommend doing it. It is unnecessary to use the array to get the song, you are writing additional code needlessly.

```js
//declare a sound variable
var sound;

//function to generate a random number
function generateRandomNumber() {
   return Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
}

function playSound(){
   //assign random number to x
   var x = generateRandomNumber();

   //if the sound exists pause, otherwise 
   //create a new instance of the sound object
   if (sound) {
      sound.pause();
   } else {
      sound = new Audio();
   }

   if(x == 1) {
      sound.src = "http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3";
   } else if( x == 2 ) {
      sound.src = "http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/The%20Entertainer.mp3";
   }
   //play sound
   sound.play();
}

document.getElementById('soundbutton').addEventListener('click', playSound);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="soundbutton">Press</a>
```

Comment: Good but you need to keep track if an Audio() is already instantiated, cause clicking 10 times will make you have 10 audio playing in the same time. On next random just change source and play it again. not create a new audio player.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a switch at all. Just get a random number between 0 and the number of sound files you have, then use that as the index to an array of those sound files.

```js
var sounds = [
    "Pokemon.mp3",
    "Wonderwall.mp3",
    "Tacobell.mp3",
    "Starwars.mp3",
    "Mcdonalds.mp3",
    "KFC.mp3",
    "Salvia.mp3",
    "Allstar.mp3",
    "Funtime.mp3",
    "Clothes.mp3"
];

var sound;

//function used to create a random number
function generateRandomNumber(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

function playSound() {
  //create a random number and assign to x
  var x = generateRandomNumber(sounds.length - 1);
  var soundSrc = sounds[x];
  //create a new instance of the audio object
  if (sound) {
      sound.pause();
  } else {
      sound = new Audio();
  }
  sound.src = soundSrc;
  //play the sound
  sound.play();
}

document.getElementById('soundbutton').addEventListener('click', playSound);
```

```html
<a href="#" id="soundbutton">Press</a>
```

Comment: I dont think `sound.stop` works, I think it's `sound.pause()`. at least it was throwing errors for me